# How to run multiple AWS services with moto_server

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, moto

I am trying to run integration tests against AWS services, to do this I choose moto. Because I am doing this under Java, I wanted to run moto_server, and execute these tests against this mock. The problem I have is that moto_server allows only one service to be mocked. And I need a couple of them. I can lunch moto_server instance per service, but this way it will not share state (like EC2 instances or IAM roles). Is there another way I can mock more than one service with moto_server?

Comment: Can you share your code so far?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like, you can't run more than one AWS service using moto `standalone` server. If you want say both `ec2` and `acm` services to be run with moto, run both these commands,

```
moto_server ec2 -p 5000 -H 0.0.0.0
moto_server acm -p 5001 -H 0.0.0.0
```

However, if you want multiple services of AWS for testing, you could consider `localstack` [here](https://localstack.cloud/). It claims that it internally uses moto and few other open source applications. Though it has a few limitations, such as ACM service not available, implementation of few AWS APIs varies slightly.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/4418

You can run all services at once with the standalone server by not passing the service name...

```
moto_server -p 5000 -H 0.0.0.0
```